# Adding CSS to HTML file using "style="

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a piece of CSS I wish to only be executed on non-mobile devices:

```
<div id="hornav" class="pull-middle visible-lg" style=" padding-left: 300px">
```

I have found a piece of CSS which supposedly allows me to target specific screen resolutions which will mean I can have certain CSS on non-mobile devices only

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 760px){}
```

How do I add this to my HTML file without writing a CSS file separately, so that it applies to the above `style="padding-left: 300px"`?

Comment: You want the `padding-left: 300px` to apply when not on mobile?

Comment: That's correct @LGSon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it like this to your head element

```
<head>
  <style>
    @media only screen and (min-width: 760px){
      #hornav {
        padding-left: 300px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

And have your element look like this

```
<div id="hornav" class="pull-middle visible-lg"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `<head></head>`

```
 <style> @media only screen and (min-width: 760px){} </style>
```

Comment: Won't that mean it'll apply to everything though?

Comment: You can also put <style></style> inside your <body></body> if you wan't it to be only on that single page. Or create 2 separate <head>'s, which i wouldn't recommend for one single line.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply add the padding *inside* of the media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 760px){
  #hornav{padding-left:300px}
}
```

Comment: Hey Jacob, at the moment that code is being treated as plaintext when I add it to my html, do you know how I can fix that

Comment: @BarneyChambers When you add CSS to a page, you wrap it in a `<style>` element. However, it is a lot easier to maintain and edit if you save it in a seperate `.css` file, then add a link to it in the head like: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycssfile.css">`